# Нахождение точки пересечения линии и окружности

Tags: javascript, html, css

Что поможет найти точку пересечения линии с окружностью?

Есть окружность радиусом в **`r`**. И у неё есть точка по центру ***`a`*** и где-то ещё внутри ***`b`***.

Каким образом можно найти точку пересечения линии с окружностью, которая будет проходить через точки ***`a`*** и ***`b`***?

Comment: Вам нужно построить уравнение окружности и прямой и решить их систему

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Найти расстояние L между a и b, потом

```
x_i = ax + (bx-ax)*r/L
y_i = ay + (by-ay)*r/L
```

(я надеюсь, что "точка по центру a" есть центр окружности)

Comment: Через подобные треугольники? Странно, что речь идет только об одной точке))) В JS `L = Math.hypot(ax-bx, ay-by);` - все достаточно просто)

Comment: Хм, спасибо, благодарю. Да а и есть центр окружности